# time overflow when I try to insert 24:00:00 in a time field

Tags: python, postgresql

Context:
I am importing a csv where the client uses a field to accumulate the working hours of their employees. Some pass 26:59:59 and send an error because timestamp only accepts values from 0 to 23.

```
psycopg2.errors.DatetimeFieldOverflow: date/time field value out of range: "24:05:31"
```

Does anyone know how to save this data in postgres?

Comment: Use field type of `interval` instead of `time`

Comment: The `time` data type represents "time of the day". I am sure you never had a clock that displays `24:05:31` or `26:59:59`. If you want to store a duration then use `interval` (or integer to store seconds)

Comment: Yeap, the solution was use interval 
Thanks